# CommonsRequestLoggingFilter usage with logstash StructuredArgument

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, logstash

In my SpringBoot app I use CommonsRequestLoggingFilter to log all my incomming requests and it works fine :

```
     CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter() {
        @Override
        protected boolean shouldLog(HttpServletRequest request) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void beforeRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
            this.logger.debug(message);
        }
    };
```

But to make debugging easier in a Kibana environnement, i would to like to append several information to the core log. At other places in my code I use `StructuredArguments` like this and it works fine :

```
this.logger.debug(message, keyValue("foo","bar"));
```

But inside CommonsRequestLoggingFilter the logger used is org.apache.commons.logging.Log, that is not letting me add any parameter to my log.

Is there any way to override the logger used in CommonsRequestLoggingFilter ? Or other ideas ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot override the `logger` in `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` because it is final.

You have at least two options.

The first one is to create a new class that extends `AbstractRequestLoggingFilter` and use it instead of `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`. In this new class you can do what you wish like :

```
    org.slf4j.Logger yourLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("MyRequestLoggingFilter");
    ...
    @Override
    protected void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
       yourLogger.debug(message, keyValue("foo","bar"));
    }
```

To continue to use everything as it is you can use `MDC`, to add new key/values to the logger. It is not the same thing, but it will log the values. You can, for example extend `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` and put the values in MDC, or in each "context" add the values, so the logger will log them.

Example if extending `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`:

```
    @Override
    protected void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
       MDC.put("orderId", "123");
       super.afterRequest(request, message);
       MDC.remove("orderId");
    }
```

If using JSON logger the aspect will be more or less this one:

```
{
  ...
  "message": "Some message",
  ...
  "orderId": "123"
}
```

The samples were taken from the next link, where you can also get more details: https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/structured-logging/